# Splitting function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, split

I am trying to write a function that takes a string and a delimiter as an input and return an array of strings. For some reason, the following code runs into segmentation error. I am wondering what could be the problem?

```
char** split(string thing, char delimiter){

    thing+='\0';//add null to signal end of string
    char**split_string = new char*[100];

    int i=0,j=0,l=0; //indexes- i is the ith letter in the string
                    // j is the jth letter in the lth string of the new array
    int length = thing.length();
    while (i < length){
            if ((thing[i]!=delimiter && thing[i]!='\0')){
                    split_string[l][j]=thing[i];
                    j++;
            }
            else {
                    j=0; //reset j-value
                    l++;
            }
            i++;
    }

    return split_string;
```

}

Comment: Why don't you "split" the source string into a vector of strings? Why bother with pointers and dynamic allocation (especially if you don't have 100 "tokens" in the source string)?

Comment: `split_string[l]` is an uninitialized pointer containing some random garbage, pointing to some random location in memory. `split_string[l][j]=thing[i]` then attempts to write to that random memory location.

Comment: Have you tried googling the Error message? Learn what exactly it means? Then It would be simple to find where you went wrong.

Comment: As for a possible (and IMO simpler) way to "split" strings, remember that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can be used with an arbitrary *delimiter* character.

Comment: Lastly about your problem, you allocate an array of 100 *pointers*, but what do you make all those pointers actually point to?

Comment: For this situation (which I presume is primarily to get familiar with C++), using a `vector<string>` might be more appropriate and might avoid the segmentation fault altogether.

Answer (score 1):

After doing 
`char**split_string = new char*[100];`

You still need to initialize each of the 100 char * pointers you created.

```
static const size_t str_len = 50; //assuming length will not exceed 
for( size_t ix = 0 ; ix < 100 ; ++ix){
    split_string[ix] = new char[str_len];
}
```

Also you need to make sure while writing to split_string you do not exceed the allocated memory in which case its 50 and you don't have splited strings more then 100.

Answer (score 1):

Better split a `std::string` to `std::vector<std::string>`. Use the function below

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string token;
    while (getline(ss, token, delim))
        result.push_back(token);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I guess OP is looking to write an implementation for split function, whereas `getline` does all checks internally.

Answer (score 0):

Each `char *` has to be individually initialized like this.

```
int len = 100;

char**split_string = new char*[len];  // len holds the number of pointers

for(int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
    split_string[k] = new char[500]; // holds len of string (here Max word size is considered 500)
}
```

In C++, sticking to the usage of [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) would be more recommended to reduce complexity and increase readablity.

Your code **will fail** to catch hold of the last substring as you are breaking out of *while-loop* just before finding `\0`. To fix that you need to change the `while (i < length)` to `while (i <= length)`.

Using **vector < string >**:

```
vector<string> split(string thing, char delimiter){
    int len = 100;
    vector<string> v;
    char c[500];
    int i=0,j=0; 
    int length = thing.length();
    while (i <= length){
        if ( thing[i] != delimiter && thing[i] != '\0') {
            c[j]=thing[i];
            j++;
        }
        else {
            c[j] = '\0';
            v.push_back(c);
            memset(c, 0, sizeof c);
            j = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return v;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/VcK01D).

Answer (score 0):

1) Please allocate memory for each substring (something like char[l] = new char[100]) when ever you find a new substring.

As you do not know the number of substring in the beginning itself, please consider using vector. consider using vector < string > split_string. In the loop when ever you find a new sub string you just push that string in the vector. In the end, you will have all the splitted strings in the vector.